# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE syntax error

Tags: mysql, cron

working with MySQL: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

I am trying to cron a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE job to run twice a day. I am having a remarkably difficult time sorting my syntax. Currently, I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --user=dbuser --password="dbuserpassword" --database=DSDB --local-infile --execute "

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/mnt/hqsccm/TSReport.CSV'
INTO TABLE temptable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@compname,@imgdate,@imgname,@imgsttime,@imgendtime,@tottime,@engname,@engemail) set ComputerName=@compname,ImagingDate=@imgdate,ImageName=@imgname,ImageSTartTime=@imgsttime,ImageEndTime=@imgendtime,TotalTime=@tottime,EngineerName=@engname,EngineerEmail=@engemail;

TRUNCATE HQSCCMmachines;

INSERT INTO HQSCCMmachines (ComputerName,ImagingDate,ImageName,ImageSTartTime,ImageEndTime,TotalTime,EngineerName,EngineerEmail)
SELECT (ComputerName,ImagingDate,ImageName,ImageSTartTime,ImageEndTime,TotalTime,EngineerName,EngineerEmail)
  FROM temptable

TRUNCATE temptable;
"
```

And I keep getting this:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'temptable' at line 5
```

Help?

Comment: Can you post the first 2-3 rows of your CSV file `TSReport.CSV` ?

Comment: I think the problem is simply that you need to add a semicolon after `FROM temptable` on the second-to-last code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work(if file and table exist)-

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/mnt/hqsccm/TSReport.CSV'
INTO TABLE temptable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(@compname,@imgdate,@imgname,@imgsttime,@imgendtime,@tottime,@engname,@engemail) set ComputerName=@compname,ImagingDate=@imgdate,ImageName=@imgname,ImageSTartTime=@imgsttime,ImageEndTime=@imgendtime,TotalTime=@tottime,EngineerName=@engname,EngineerEmail=@engemail;

TRUNCATE HQSCCMmachines;

INSERT INTO HQSCCMmachines (ComputerName,ImagingDate,ImageName,ImageSTartTime,ImageEndTime,TotalTime,EngineerName,EngineerEmail)
SELECT ComputerName,ImagingDate,ImageName,ImageSTartTime,ImageEndTime,TotalTime,EngineerName,EngineerEmail
  FROM temptable;

TRUNCATE temptable;
```

Comment: Now I get "ERROR 1241 (21000) at line 10: Operand should contain 1 column(s)" I took out the variables.